# How to sort a list in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I need help for sorting the variable in JavaScript, below is my code. I want to sort surchargeTypeVariableList in the code. I am getting only one value in the front end. Actually it has 6 values but in the unordered list. I want make it in a ascending order.

```
_createSurcharges : function () {
            var label, amount, sortedArray = [], displayPremiumHeader = false;
            if (this.surchargeList && this.surchargeList.length > 0) {
                array.forEach(this.surchargeList, lang.hitch(this, function (surcharge) {
                    debugger;
                    label = this.getContentItemLabelWithJurisdiction(this.policyContentPrefix + surcharge.displayKey, surcharge.displayKeyValue, this.jurisdiction);

                    if (surcharge.surchargeTypeVariableList && surcharge.surchargeTypeVariableList.length > 0) {
                        // Modifies Java based substitutions to work for dojo converts {x} to ${x}
                        label = this._modifyTemplate(label);
                        label = string.substitute(label, surcharge.surchargeTypeVariableList);
                    }

                    surcharge.label = label;
                    surcharge.surchargeTypeVariableList.sort(function (a, b) {
                        if (a.fieldType === label) {
                            return 1;
                        } else if (b.fieldType === label) {
                            return -1;
                        }

                        return 0;

                    });

                    if (surcharge.premium > 0) {
                        amount = currencies.reformat(surcharge.premium);
                        displayPremiumHeader = true;
                    }
                }));


                sortedArray = this.surchargeList.sort(this._sortByDisplayOrder);

                amount = null;
                domConstruct.place(string.substitute(this.col1Template, {
                    "label" : label
                }), this.otherChargesListNode, "last");
                if (amount) {
                    domConstruct.place(string.substitute(this.col2Template, {
                        "amount" : amount
                    }), this.otherChargesListNode, "last");
                }

                if (!displayPremiumHeader) {
                    this.set("premiumHeader", "");
                }
            } else {
                domClass.add(this.domNode, "hide");
            }
        },

        /**
         * sort comparator<br/>
         * 
         * @private
         * @instance
         */
        _sortByDisplayOrder : function (displayOrderable1, displayOrderable2) {
            "use strict";
            if (displayOrderable1.displayOrder === displayOrderable2.displayOrder) {
                return 0;
            }
            return (displayOrderable1.displayOrder > displayOrderable2.displayOrder) ? 1 : -1;
        },

        /**
         * Modifies Java based substitutions to work for dojo<br/>
         * converts {x} to ${x}
         * Note, there is a special case handling for formats such as $null <small>per accident</small>
         * we assume a single substitution in this case.  TODO  verify this assumption
         * 
         * @private
         * @instance
         */
        _modifyTemplate : function (template) {
            var t = template;
            if (template.indexOf("$null") !== -1) {
                t = template.replace("$null", "${0}");
            } else {
                t = t.replace(/(\{[0-9]+\})/g, "$$$1");
            }
            return t;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Refactor your code and put only the part of the code that sort the variable please. By the way, what type of variable is it? Exist `sort`method in Array prototype in the case of `Array`

Answer (score 2):

In case `surchargeTypeVariableList` is array of strings, consider using [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) without compare function.

In this way your will sort your array based on Unicode code point order.

Example:

```js
var data = ['c', 'd', 'a', 'b'];
data.sort(); 
alert(data);
```

From your example:

```
surcharge.surchargeTypeVariableList.sort(function (a, b) {
                        if (a.fieldType === label) {
                            return 1;
                        } else if (b.fieldType === label) {
                            return -1;
                        }

                        return 0;

                    });
```

Change to:

```
surcharge.surchargeTypeVariableList.sort();
```

Notes:
Question does not provide an example of `surchargeTypeVariableList` variable we can just guess on its type. Please update your question with more details and possibly with a minimal viable example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @learner I am glad my answer help you out, please consider to accept my answer if you have founded useful (just click the V green icon on the left side) thanks! :)